# In my example, can I use parentheses in such a way?

Tags: parentheses

This is for writing a research paper.

Some of the different regressions include higher polynomial orders with (or without) the birthday variable

Comment: You can, but there is no need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality of any reasoned argument regarding the appropriate use of punctuation will depend on how closely the punctuation reflects the meaning and subtext of what you want to convey. If you want to convey the sense that 'without it' is less important, and just put in 'as an aside', then your phrase would be parenthetical and the brackets appropriate.

However, I suspect that you are talking about two equally viable alternatives. The value given to both would be absolutely equal if no punctuation marks were put in until the full stop at the end of the sentence. Commas instead of your brackets would give a slightly greater value to the 'with it' part. The use of en dashes would give even more emphasis to it.

It's important to remember that punctuation reflects a particular direction, speed and flow of thought. In this sense, a Parenthesis is a [rhetorical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29) term. There are some nineteenth century examples you can take a look at [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8TsJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false).